# What's a typical life time for an OAuth access_token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm working with a company that's implementing OAuth, and currently they're supplying an `access_token` with a lifetime of 180 seconds. This seems short to me, so I'm trying to figure out what a **typical** lifetime for an `access_token` is, from what other companies do on the web.

I've seen on the web that:

- Twitter [lets them live forever](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/faq)
- Facebook [expires them after ~60 days](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#termtokens)

So it seems to me that 180 seconds is way too short, as it will force developers to constantly have to use the `refresh_token` to request a new `access_token`.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: At first I was asking "What's a reasonable life time for an OAuth access_token?". I've changed the question to "What's a typical life time for an OAuth access_token?", as I think this is closer to what I actually meant.**

Comment: It relies on how sensible is your company data. With a long life token stored by weak apps, that app can get hacked and then someone will use that token to read your customer data. Usually 180 seconds is a reasonable time to allow a program query your API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

What is reasonable all depends on the company policy and its OAuth implementation.

Long Answer:

The access token lifetime is really up to the supplier of the token i.e. the Authorization Server of your partner company and its policy.

I would agree that 3 minutes is very short but the company's security policy may demand that on revocation of certain permissions or account removal, access for clients who were granted access based on those permissions is disabled within no more than 3 minutes. The fact that this comes at the cost of quite significant network and processing overhead is something that is calculated in (hopefully).

The cost (as in: overhead) of that decision also depends on the usage of the token itself. It it is used infrequently but always in burst mode, the overhead may be relatively low. If it is used frequently but just for one API call each time, then the overhead is relatively large and thus the cost higher.

Most environments wouldn't require immediate removal of all delegated access on the spot and would find it affordable to deal with a delay of at least 1 hour.

On the other hand, Twitter and Facebook are implementing OAuth in such a way that they can afford long-lived access tokens: when the Resource Server receives an access token, the permissions associated with the account that issued the token are checked. Of course for performance reasons the Resource Server will cache those results (for the sake of the discussion, say for a duration of 3 minutes) but effectively it yields the same result, pushing the "refresh overhead" to the Resource Server instead of the Client. (Note that this somewhat defeats the purpose of using structured self-contained access tokens such as JWTs).

The approach of Twitter and Facebook works if you don't need/want to explicitly authenticate your clients again within reasonable bounds. Since Twitter and Facebook also don't authenticate their users very often, that approach make sense for them.

I guess you could say that each use case is different: it all depends on what you want and how you implement it. And your company and Facebook may not be comparable because they have different tokens, Resource Server implementations and restrictions on client (and user) authentication.

Comment: Hans Z, i'm a big fan of your music, didn't know you were on SO too :D Nice explanation though!